# Not able to update datagridview data in windows form application C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, desktop-application

I have two forms in my windows form application. I have a datagridview in form1, I am able to update the data of the datagridview from the form1. Now, i need to update the datagridview from form2. I am calling the same method from form2 which i am using to update the datagridview from form1.

While calling the method from form2, in debugging i can see that it updating the datasource of the datagridview, but it not updating the data on UI.

I know it is a repeat question. I have tried many different ways. I have also tried the concept of MdiContainer, but not useful for me.

I have below methods in form1 which doing job to update data of datagridview(CustomerList) and it updating the datagridview on UI also while calling BindCustomerList() method from form1

```
//form1
public void BindCustomerList()
{
     CustomerList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
     CustomerList.DataSource = FetchEmpDetails();
     CustomerList.ClearSelection();
}

public DataTable FetchEmpDetails()
{
      if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
      {
            sqlCon.Open();
      }
      DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
      sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_customers", sqlCon);
      sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActionType", "FetchData");
      SqlDataAdapter sqlSda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
      sqlSda.Fill(dtData);
      return dtData;
}
```

I am calling BindCustomerList() from form2 using below code, which updating the datasource of the datagridview(CustomerList) but not updating on UI in form1.

```
//form2 button click event    
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();    //object of form1 in form2
    this.Close();                 //closing form2 on button click
    form1.BindCustomerList();     //calling form1 method to update datagridview.
}
```

Comment: This: `Form1 form1 = new Form1();` generates a new Form of type `Form1`, completely unrelated to the existing instance of `Form1`.

Comment: My suggestion is to use a manager class that is responsible for all the operations related to the loading and presenting the data. I will include your `BindCustomerList()` and `FetchEmpDetails()`. When you first initialize the class object, pass the instance of the DataGridView used to present the data. You can then call these methods when needed, other Form classes included. Or, pass the instance of Form1 to Form2 and use this instance to call the public methods. It would be better if Form1 implemented a known Interface.

Comment: @Jimi Can you give me like any existing example same as you mentioned in your 2nd comment, I am new to windows form.

Comment: You should specify what Form2 is doing. Why do you need to reload the data from that interface to present it in another (Form1)? What's happening? The Buttons is named `btnSave`, but you're not saving, you're reloading (from what you're showing here). If you're actually saving data back to the database, in Form1 just subscribe to the `FormClosed` event of Form2 when you create the instance, before showing it. When Form2 closes, the event is raised and you can call `BindCustomerList()` from the event handler. Thus Form2 doesn't need to know anything about the data fetching procedure.

Comment: That being said, neither Form1 or Form2 should know anything about the data these classes are presenting. You should have class objects that are responsible for storing and fetching the data. Your Forms should only be used to present the data to the User: these classes should not contain the logic required to interact with the data source. This way, you have all the data managing in one place only. If something changes in relation to the source of data, your Forms won't require any change, just the *data manager* class will. The presenter classes will always receive the same data objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your form2 constructor accept a datatable parameter, and assign it to the DataSource of the other grid:

```
public Form2(DataTable dt){
  InitializeComponent();

  otherDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
}
```

And when you make a new Form2, in form1, after you already called BindCustomerList at least once:

```
var f = new Form2(CustomerList.DataSource as DataTable);
```

> I am calling BindCustomerList() from form2

It won't work; bindCustomerList sets the DataSource of form1's datagridview; this is nothing to do with form2. To have the forms share data you have to pass the data you want to share, such as in my code above (for example)

Comment: `BindCustomerList()` is meant to reload the data, using a StoredProcedure (the operations in Form2 are unknown, but this seems to be the desired outcome) -- You forgot `public Form2() : this(null) { }`

Comment: It worked after I added datagridview parameter in form2 constructor and then updating its datasource by calling FetchEmpDetails().

Comment: That sounds wrong. If you want to have a datagridview on form1, and a datagridview on form2 and have them share details so that any change you make in form2's datagridview is also observed in form1's datagridview, then you pass the datatable model that both DGV are to share, so that both DGV have the same datasource. You don't have your form2 fetching anything; form1 does that. Form1 does the fetch, then hand the data it has fetched to form2. Don't overcomplicate form2. Form2 doesn't need to know anything about form1, or FetchEmpDetails, it just needs to accept a datatable and bind it

Comment: @Jimi was the comment to me?

Comment: 50/50. The *You forgot...* part is on your 50% alone, I'm not sure the OP knows what to do with it. The *StoredProcedure* part is meant to trigger a response from the OP, since it's not clear what Form2 is actually doing with the data. The data sharing/handling design appear flawed (commented about it on the question).

Comment: @Jimi Why provide a parameterless constructor for Form2? It doesn't seem to solve anything, but potentially causes a problem (OP doesn't heed the advice to change form1 code to `new Form2(.. some datatable here...)`,  leaves the original `new Form2()` code in and there is no compiler error because of the parameterless constructor, wonders why my advice doesn't work)

Comment: The parameter-less constructor is for the Form designer, not related to the code presented here. If you add a constructor that expects a parameter, the parameter-less constructor need to call the new constructor, which in turn calls `InitializeCompoenent()`. If the empty constructor is missing, you can (will) have some problem with the Form Designer, most notable a *the [UserControl]/[Custom Control] is undeclared [...]. To prevent data loss the designer has been disabled...* message that prevents the Form designer from showing up, replaced by the famous notification that asks tfx the problem.

Comment: Since this notification doesn't appear all the time, just *now and then*, when one doesn't know what causes it, it creates some discomfort (and posts to SO :).

Comment: I think I can honestly say I've never in my life experienced a problem omitting a parameterless constructor from a Form, but your mileage clearly varies and I hold you in high regard as one of the smartest contributors I regularly come across here so cheers for the tip. It probably doesn't need working into the answer so long as the comments remain..